# Filter data by date and color in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an Excel table that has 3 columns with dates of 2023 with four different background colors. I would like to filter this data by date and color at the same time. Is this possible?

I tried to apply advanced filters and create some functions in VBA but without success. I need to filter this table data, selecting the cells that have an expecific date and a color. Example: filter all the cells that are light green and have 26-feb-23 as it content.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Are the cells coloured with conditional formatting? If yes, filter on the conditions, if possible